# Segue from tableview to detail doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm building a table view for shops in our town, and I'd like to be able to click on the name of the shop to see some more details. You can find some pictures of the main.storyboard and the files [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B66972SsSRztS01jS1pTR0htQlk). I also added a video of the problem with the clicking.

The code of the masterViewController is mentioned below:

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Properties
var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
var winkels = [Winkel]()

// MARK: - View Setup
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    winkels = [
        Winkel(category:"Literature", name:"Standaard"),
        Winkel(category:"Literature", name:"Acco"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"H&M"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"C&A"),
        Winkel(category:"Clothing", name:"Patio"),
        Winkel(category:"Restaurants", name:"De 46"),
        Winkel(category:"Restaurants", name:"Het hoekske"),
        Winkel(category:"Supermarkets", name:"Carrefour"),
        Winkel(category:"Supermarkets", name:"Colruyt")
    ]

    winkels.sortInPlace({ $0.name < $1.name })

    if let splitViewController = splitViewController {
        let controllers = splitViewController.viewControllers
        detailViewController = (controllers[controllers.count - 1] as! UINavigationController).topViewController as? DetailViewController
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = splitViewController!.collapsed
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table View
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return winkels.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let winkel = winkels[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel!.text = winkel.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = winkel.category
    return cell
}

// MARK: - Segues
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
        if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let winkel = winkels[indexPath.row]
            let controller = (segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController).topViewController as! DetailViewController
            controller.detailWinkel = winkel
            controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController?.displayModeButtonItem()
            controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        }
    }
 }

}
```

The last part shows the segue to the next navigation controller (named showDetail, and is of kind "show Detail (e.g. replace)".

Below is the code of the detailViewController:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var detailDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var WinkelImageView: UIImageView!

var detailWinkel: Winkel? {
    didSet {
        configureView()
    }
}

func configureView() {
    if let detailWinkel = detailWinkel {
        if let detailDescriptionLabel = detailDescriptionLabel, WinkelImageView = WinkelImageView {
            detailDescriptionLabel.text = detailWinkel.name
            WinkelImageView.image = UIImage(named: detailWinkel.name)
            title = detailWinkel.category
        }
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong so that the clicking won't work.. Thanks in advance for teaching me how to fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the method didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the tableview in the first class.  In this, you will perform the segue that actually moves from one ViewController to another.